# jQuery containment animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I've a problem with the animation method.

```
<div id="containment">
    <div id="child1">C1</div>
    <div id="child2">C2</div>
    <div id="child3">C3</div>
</div
```

C1 to C3 are draggable elements, and I haven't applied any constraint on it, because when I'm out of #containment, I automatically resize it.

```
$("#containment > div").bind("dragstop", function(event, ui) {
    var size = $.extend({}, $("#containment").data("originalSize"));
    $.each($("#containment > div"), function(index, d) {
        width = parseInt($(d).css("left"), 10) + parseInt($(d).outerWidth(), 10);
        height = parseInt($(d).css("top"), 10) + parseInt($(d).outerHeight(), 10);
        size.width = (width > size.width) ? (width + 50) : size.width;
        size.height = (height > size.height) ? (height + 50) : size.height;
    });

    $("#containment").animate({
        width: size.width,
        height: size.height
    }, 'slow');
});
```

Problem is, when dragstop is fired, the child I moved out is hidden and appears only when the #containment animation is over it.

In my Screen B1 and B2 have the same size, just B1 isn't totally visible because animation is running...

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Are you using [ **draggable** ](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)? - What is the behavior you would like?

Comment: Always see the child div (that appears on orange on the screen) and not wait that the parent is big enough to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, but if you have 'overflow:hidden' from the div#containment, when you drag the node, any part of it will be obscured by the parent div. (Even though it's outside the boundaries of the parent container, DOM-wise, it's still a child).  Alternatively, you could move the child node outside of the parent div inside your dragstop listener.

Comment: My containment isn't in "overflow: hidden" mode, so the best solution is to put children out while animation is performing. It's a little bit annoying to do this but I think that I'vent another solution...